# How to block access folder that not has index file

Tags: php, xampp

I using xampp for my project. Now i have a problem

Example i have a project like

```
myproject\
|-subfolder\
|  |---example.php
|-index.php
```

Now, if i process subfolder in my address like

```
localhost/myproject/subfolder
```

i will get a list of files in subfolder (b/c subfolder haven't index file).

Have anyway to block access that (not used index file? ). That should show any message instead of list files in the folder

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure your apache httpd.conf file, change something like:

```
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
```

To:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
```

And restart your apach service.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a specific file to show the message:

For instance

localhost/myproject/subfolder/message.html

This will then show the message and not all the files.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Index feature of Apache and is designed to help with easy file navigation. Obviously this is undesirable on some servers. To turn it off you need to edit Apache's config file which is usually found in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` on Ubuntu or  `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` on CentOS / RedHat but could be somewhere else, you did not specify operating system in question. Anyway, find it and edit it.

Search for `Indexes` in this file and change the value to `-Indexes`.

Then restart Apache with the following command:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

(on Ubuntu)

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

(on CentOS or RedHat)

Directory listing should now be switched off for all your folders.

Comment: Furthermore, turning off Indexes does not increase security. Security through obfuscation is not considered security at all.